# How to load random image from local storage on Android

Tags: android

so my question is how can I load image from local storage folder regardless of the name of the image?

here is what I have for now:

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                        "/Download/pictures/for/" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(4) + 1) + ".jpg");
```

As you can see the problem is that the solution is bad and hardcoded in a way that it loads only pictures with names from 1 to 5 (ex. 3.jpg).

kind regards!

Comment: Does you directory contain only the files you want to load or you want to pick only `.jpg` among other filetypes?

Comment: I want to pick only .jpg filetypes. br

Comment: I updated my answer to add extension filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve the list of files in the directory and pick a random item from this list:

```
File rootDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/pictures/for/");
File files[] = rootDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
    }
});
File image = files[new Random().nextInt(files.length)];
```